# How do I create a hover effect for my button?

Tags: html, css

I have a question. I am wondering how can I create a border that increases the width for my button on hover. I tried to create a border but what happened is it created a border on the inside of my button. The image shows what is supposed to happen. I began thinking it had something to with padding but even if that is the case I have no idea how I would go about doing it.

[image]

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./assets/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bellefair&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Barlow+Condensed&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Barlow&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

  <title>Frontend Mentor | Space tourism website</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="top-logo">
    <img class="logo" src="assets/shared/logo.svg" alt="logo">
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div class="nav">
    <a href="#"><span class="nav-number">00</span>Home</a>
    <a href="#"><span class="nav-number">01</span>Destination</a>
    <a href="#"><span class="nav-number">02</span>Crew</a>
    <a href="#"><span class="nav-number">03</span>Technology</a>
  </div>
  <div class="description-container">
    <h5>So, you want to travel to</h5>
    <h1>Space</h1>
    <p>Let’s face it; if you want to go to space, you might as well genuinely go to
    outer space and not hover kind of on the edge of it. Well sit back, and relax
    because we’ll give you a truly out of this world experience!</p>
  </div>
  <button class="btn">Explore</button>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS code:

```
body {
  background-image: url('../assets/home/background-home-desktop.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: black;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
hr {
  width: 40%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
h1 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 9.375rem;
  font-family: 'Bellefair', serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: normal;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 6.25rem;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  font-family: 'Bellefair', serif;
  font-weight: normal;
}
h4 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: 'Bellefair', serif;
}
h5 {
  margin: 0 0 0 10px;
  font-size: 1.75rem;
  letter-spacing: 4.75px;
  font-family: 'Barlow Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #D0D6F9;
}
p {
  width: 32%;
  font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
  line-height: 2;
  color: #D0D6F9;
}
.logo {
  margin-right: 70px;
}
.top-logo {
  margin: 53px 0 0 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.nav > a {
  color: grey;
  margin-right: 40px;
}
.nav-number {
  color: white;
  margin-right: 8px;
}
.nav {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 74px;
  right: 230px;
  background: hsl(0 0% 100% / 0.1);
  backdrop-filter: blur(1rem);
}
.description-container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 150px;
  left: 150px;
}
.btn {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 150px;
  right: 150px;
  width:250px;
height:250px;
border-radius: 50%;
border:none;
background-color:white;
font-family: 'Bellefair', serif;
font-size: 2rem;
font-weight: normal;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
.btn:hover {
  
}
```

Comment: do you.want the entire thing to be clickable? or just the center white part?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `outline`:

`outline: 40px #25252e solid;`

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this??

```css
body {
  background-image: url('../assets/home/background-home-desktop.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: black;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
hr {
  width: 40%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
h1 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 9.375rem;
  font-family: 'Bellefair', serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: normal;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 6.25rem;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  font-family: 'Bellefair', serif;
  font-weight: normal;
}
h4 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: 'Bellefair', serif;
}
h5 {
  margin: 0 0 0 10px;
  font-size: 1.75rem;
  letter-spacing: 4.75px;
  font-family: 'Barlow Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #D0D6F9;
}
p {
  width: 32%;
  font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
  line-height: 2;
  color: #D0D6F9;
}
.logo {
  margin-right: 70px;
}
.top-logo {
  margin: 53px 0 0 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.nav > a {
  color: grey;
  margin-right: 40px;
}
.nav-number {
  color: white;
  margin-right: 8px;
}
.nav {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 74px;
  right: 230px;
  background: hsl(0 0% 100% / 0.1);
  backdrop-filter: blur(1rem);
}
.description-container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 150px;
  left: 150px;
}
.btn {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 150px;
  right: 150px;
  width:250px;
height:250px;
border-radius: 50%;
border:none;
background-color:white;
font-family: 'Bellefair', serif;
font-size: 2rem;
font-weight: normal;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
.btn:hover {
 outline:50px solid gray;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./assets/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bellefair&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Barlow+Condensed&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Barlow&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

  <title>Frontend Mentor | Space tourism website</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="top-logo">
    <img class="logo" src="assets/shared/logo.svg" alt="logo">
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div class="nav">
    <a href="#"><span class="nav-number">00</span>Home</a>
    <a href="#"><span class="nav-number">01</span>Destination</a>
    <a href="#"><span class="nav-number">02</span>Crew</a>
    <a href="#"><span class="nav-number">03</span>Technology</a>
  </div>
  <div class="description-container">
    <h5>So, you want to travel to</h5>
    <h1>Space</h1>
    <p>Let’s face it; if you want to go to space, you might as well genuinely go to
    outer space and not hover kind of on the edge of it. Well sit back, and relax
    because we’ll give you a truly out of this world experience!</p>
  </div>
  <button class="btn">Explore</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. Now I know for the future

Comment: That's the same answer I gave. The reason adding border does not work is because you set a specific width and height.